# How to change link of images in iis manager?

Tags: php, magento, iis

i had created a magento website. When I had created this site locally through localhost the link was - `http://localhost:3115`

Now that I changed it the link is `http://www.localhost.com`

But now my images and other links go to the old url - `http://localhost:3115/`

How can I tackle this issue.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change in databse just go to phpmyadmin
and open table `core_config_data` and find `web/unsecure/base_url column and web/secure/base_url` you find your old url just replace with your new url and clear your cache..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, Please clear Cache

if it doesn't works than:
did you changed the base url for your magento to the new one ? if you have changed base url from old to new than images should work if you used correct code standards for magento template.

Comment: where i have to change base url